# Android - How to know GPS locations are reliable

Tags: android, gps

I'm programming an android applicaction that must do different tasks depending on movement and velocity. If the vehicle is stopped, it should do nothing. If the vehicle is moving at a  velocity range R1 (from X1 meters per second to X2 meters per second), it should do task T1. If vehicle is moving at a velocity range R2 (from X2 meters per second to X3 meters per second), it should do task T2. And so on.

I'm using the GPS of the mobile to calculate the velocity of the vehicle. So I've implemented an android.location.LocationListener to receive GPS Locations that are processed to calculate the velocity.

What I would like to know is once the user has started the mobile application, when are the GPS locations reliable? How could I know that the GPS locations are precise?

I've seen that the android.location.Location class has a method called getAccuracy and the 
android.location.LocationListener class has a method called onStatusChanged, but I'm not sure about how I should use them to achieve my goal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would use getAccuracy() to determine how accurate the GPS co-ordinates are in meters.

To understand more about onStatusChanged, I recommend reading this: [Androids onStatusChanged not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222152/androids-onstatuschanged-not-working)